# SQL query to get avg daily use excluding Saturday

Tags: mysql, sql, average

I have the following output:

```
root@localhost [hatsize]> SELECT COUNT(*) AS VMS,sysname,DAYNAME(Start),DATE(Start) from complete_ev WHERE type = 's' GROUP BY DAYOFYEAR(Start),sysname ORDER BY VMS DESC;
+-----+---------+----------------+-------------+
| VMS | sysname | DAYNAME(Start) | DATE(Start) |
+-----+---------+----------------+-------------+
|  85 | sv-esx5 | Monday         | 2013-09-16  |
|  63 | sv-esx6 | Wednesday      | 2013-09-18  |
|  60 | sv-esx5 | Monday         | 2013-09-09  |
|  55 | sv-esx6 | Monday         | 2013-09-16  |
|  52 | sv-esx6 | Monday         | 2013-09-09  |
|  51 | sv-esx5 | Wednesday      | 2013-09-18  |
|  50 | sv-esx7 | Wednesday      | 2013-09-11  |
|  44 | sv-esx4 | Monday         | 2013-09-09  |
|  43 | sv-esx4 | Tuesday        | 2013-09-10  |
|  34 | sv-esx4 | Tuesday        | 2013-09-17  |
|  34 | sv-esx7 | Monday         | 2013-09-09  |
|  34 | sv-esx4 | Monday         | 2013-09-16  |
|  34 | sv-esx7 | Tuesday        | 2013-09-17  |
|  34 | sv-esx6 | Wednesday      | 2013-09-11  |
|  34 | sv-esx7 | Monday         | 2013-09-16  |
|  30 | sv-esx5 | Wednesday      | 2013-09-11  |
|  30 | sv-esx5 | Thursday       | 2013-09-12  |
|  18 | sv-esx7 | Wednesday      | 2013-09-18  |
|  17 | sv-esx6 | Tuesday        | 2013-09-17  |
|  17 | sv-esx6 | Tuesday        | 2013-09-10  |
|  17 | sv-esx7 | Thursday       | 2013-09-12  |
|  13 | Pod130  | Wednesday      | 2013-09-11  |
|  10 | sv-esx4 | Friday         | 2013-03-22  |
|   9 | sv-esx4 | Sunday         | 2013-09-08  |
|   9 | sv-esx2 | Wednesday      | 2013-09-11  |
|   9 | sv-esx2 | Tuesday        | 2013-09-10  |
|   9 | Pod130  | Thursday       | 2013-09-12  |
|   9 | sv-esx4 | Wednesday      | 2013-09-11  |
|   9 | sv-esx5 | Friday         | 2013-09-13  |
|   9 | sv-esx4 | Friday         | 2013-09-13  |
|   9 | sv-esx2 | Monday         | 2013-09-09  |
|   9 | sv-esx5 | Tuesday        | 2013-09-10  |
|   2 | sv-esx2 | Friday         | 2012-07-27  |
+-----+---------+----------------+-------------+
33 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I like to get the daily avg for each sysname even on days when there is no use, and the other twist is that I want to exclude Saturday. I tried a few things a but I can't see to come up with the right formula. Here is a description of the table:

```
root@localhost [hatsize]> desc complete_ev;
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| EventID  | int(16)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Start    | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| End      | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Cname    | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Template | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| pod      | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| sysname  | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| type     | char(10)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Which is actually a view:

```
show create table complete_ev\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       View: complete_ev
Create View: CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `complete_ev` AS select `e`.`EventID` AS `EventID`,`e`.`Start` AS `Start`,`e`.`End` AS `End`,`e`.`Name` AS `Cname`,`e`.`template` AS `Template`,`d`.`pod` AS `pod`,`d`.`name` AS `sysname`,`d`.`type` AS `type` from (`FutEv` `e` join `equip` `d` on((`e`.`EventID` = `d`.`EventID`))) where (`e`.`Status` = _latin1'i')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the best way (imho) to do this is to create a table with a record for each date for whatever range of years you are looking at (2000 - 2025 for example).  Then do a left join from this table to your main table to get all of the dates if they have results or not.  Then exclude Saturdays in your `WHERE` clause.

This assuming you have created a table called `date_table` with all of the dates you would need.  It also assumes you have a table called `systems` with the list of systems you would use.

```
SELECT sysname, AVG(VMS)

FROM

(

SELECT COUNT(*) AS VMS, sys.sysname, DAYNAME(dt.date), dt.date 

FROM   date_table as dt

       , (SELECT sysname FROM systems) as sys

       LEFT JOIN complete_ev as ce 
       ON dt.date = DATE(ce.Start) AND sys.sysname = ce.sysname
       AND ce.type = 's'

WHERE  DAYNAME(dt.date) <> 'Saturday'

GROUP BY dt.date, sys.sysname 

) as x

GROUP BY sysname;
```

Code to create `date_table`.

```
CREATE TABLE `date_table` (
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `day_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`date`)
);
```

Comment: Edited - Changed join to LEFT JOIN and moved ce.type from WHERE clause to join.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Do you have an example on how to create the date_table? and also, why do I need a systems table?

Comment: I'll update my answer with how to create a date table.  For systems, you need a list of all possible systems on the left side of your join so that you get a record for each system and date regardless if there are results or not.  If you don't have one you could use something like this: `(SELECT DISTINCT sysname FROM complete_ev)`.

Comment: I added code to create the date_table.  I generally would use a formula in MS Excel to create INSERT statements for all of the dates from 2000 to 2025 or something like that.  Or you could also create (with Excel) a csv file with all the dates and then load it using `INFILE`.